# .htaccess to rules ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, .htaccess

Recently I switch to an ASP server and I need to translate these rules of htacces to rules of web.config. Anyone can help me?

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_RETINA [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !@2x

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1@2x.$2
# if @2x isn't available fulfill the original request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1.$2
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL Rewrite Module in IIS 7 and above provides an import feature that greatly simplifies the process of converting Apache mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL rewrite rules.

[Importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)